# Passando matriz para função por referência

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, matriz, referência

Bom dia a todos, desejo em meu código deixar o Main(); só com chamada de funções, todo trabalho é dividido em pequenas funções no documento.

Quero escrever uma matriz[3][3] em uma função e organizar e imprimir em outras funções distintas. Meu código tem como objetivo fazer a transposta de uma matriz, acredito que minha lógica esteja correta, utilizando bubble sort porém a passagem de parâmetro não está funcionando corretamente uma vez que estou usando passagem por valor e não referencia...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void receberMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Insira o valor de [%i][%i]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%i", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

}



void organizarMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j, aux;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            aux = matriz[i][j];
            matriz[i][j] = matriz[j][i];
            matriz[j][i] = aux;
        }
    }
}

void imprimirMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("[%i][%i]", i, j);
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
}



    int main(void)
    {
        int matriz[3][3];

        receberMatriz(matriz);
        imprimirMatriz(matriz);
        //organizarMatriz(matriz); desabilitei chamada para testar valores recebidos e impressos pela matriz. 

        return 0;
    }
```

Como posso trabalhar com passagem de parâmetros de uma matriz por referencia? Ou seja ponteiros...?

Comment: Parece haver só erro de lógica: https://ideone.com/cBUnXo

Comment: Realmente, depois do seu comentário olhei o código com mais atenção, muito obrigado mestre!!!

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar vou deixar a resposta. O erro de lógica que nosso colaborador [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) comentou é a seguinte:

Eu troquei as bolas ao escrever a função de impressão da matriz.

```
void imprimirMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("[%i][%i]", i, j);
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
}
```

No `printf("[%i][%i]", i, j); além de colocar duas saída de dados inteiro eu estava imprimindo o valor do índice e não da matriz. O correto é o código a seguir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void receberMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("Insira o valor de [%i][%i]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%i", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

}



void imprimirMatriz(int matriz[3][3])
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n");
    limparTela();

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("[ %i ]", matriz[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");

    }
}



void limparTela()
{
    system("cls");
}



    int main(void)
    {
        int matriz[3][3];

        receberMatriz(matriz);
        imprimirMatriz(matriz);

        return 0;
    }
```

Créditos ao [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero)